# Untracked Files on Terminal

Tags: html, github

A quick question of people on StackOverflow.

I am trying to push to GitHub but I made a mistake where I added all of the wrong files to my GitHub page.

This leads me to not push my code on the terminal and I also cannot push my code onto a website used by Namecheap.

Does anyone have solutions/recommendations towards how they can fix the problem and make sure the terminal command is clear of untracked files?

Below screenshots contain the errors.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        deleted:    ../todolist/.DS_Store

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ../../.CFUserTextEncoding

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: @AaronGarton Thank you for your view to the question!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems.

1) Looks like you cloned your repo in home directory. Due to this git is seeing all files unrelated to your project.

2) I guess you did not want to commit files under `todolist` and tried to delete them.

I can suggest below solution.

a) Create a directory like `~/project/code/git` and clone your repo again to that path.

b) Merge all required changes from previous path into newly cloned repo.

As you don't want to push `todolist` to github, you can move it to `~/project/docs/todolist`.

Alternately, you could use `.gitignore` to "tell" git to ignore `todolist` folder, but I would recommend docs folder option.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a git repo in your home directory. Try this:

1. Remove `.git` folder in your home directory which cause the problem

   `rm -rf ~/.git`
2. Clone your repo into another directory
3. Copy and overwrite all of your modified files
4. Push your changes

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! Much appreciated 